# Show that $E / \sim $ is an affine space over $V/U$

Tags: equivalence-relations, affine-geometry

Let $E$ be an affine space over the vector space $V$, and let $U \subseteq V$ be a vector subspace. We define the equivalence relation 
$$P \sim Q := \exists v \in U \text{ such that } P = Q + v$$
on $E$.

I have to show that $E / \sim$ is an affine space over the quotient space $V/U$.

Therefore, I would simply check the properties of an affine space, for example
$$P + 0 = P.$$
Since we work on $E / \sim$, and since we defined $\sim$ on $E$, its elements have to be equivalence classes. Therefore, I actually have to show something like
$$[P] + 0 = [P].$$
Now I'm wondering which rules of addition I have to apply. We've already proven that on a quotient space such as $V/U$ I'm allowed to write something like
$$[v] + [w] = [v + w].$$
Is there something similar for the addition on affine spaces?

Comment: You should indeed define an addition of vectors of $V/U$ on $E/\sim$ in order to endow it with an affine space structure. $[P]+[v]=[P+v]$ seems like a nice idea, don't you think?

Comment: Thanks for editing my formatting! Let me take a guess: In order to prove the statement above, I have to show that $$[P + v] = [P' + v']$$ for $$[P] = [P']$$ and $$[v] = [v'].$$

Comment: Yes, you need to do that to prove that the addition I suggested is well-defined. Once this is done you can try proving that the axioms of affince spaces hold.

Comment: And I guess I already figured it out. Assume $$[P] = [P'] ^ [v] = [v']$$. Then $$P' \in [P] => P' ~ P <=> \exists u \in U: P' = P + u (and thus \exists u' \in U: v' = v + u').$$ This leads to $$P' +  v' = P + v + u + u'$$ and since $$u + u' \in U$$ it follows that $$P' + v' ~ P + v => [P' + v'] = [P + v].$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct :) The rest shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: You can find tips about formatting at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (but I'm not sure everything works in comments).

Comment: Yeah, already trying to work with that, guess it takes some time to learn, haha. I still have a small question about the task as it seems. It's right that I have to show that $$[P] + 0 = [P],$$ isn't it? Intuitively, I wouldn't assume that $$0 = [0],$$ therefore I couldn't make a use of the additional rules I proved before. Am I working under a false premise here?

Comment: You're trying to prove that $E/\sim$ is an affine space over $V/U$, so you need to prove that $[P]+0_{V/U} = [P]$. And $0_{V/U}=[0]$ in $V/U$.

Comment: We learned that U defines an equivalence relation R on V with $$v R w := v - w \in U.$$ Thus, if $$0 = [0],$$ then $$v R [0] <=> v - 0 \in U$$ could only be satisfied by $$v = 0,$$ but this only holds for $$v \in V\U ,$$ (meaning the difference of V and U) doesn't it?

Comment: What I wanted to say / ask is: If your statement is true, then I'm not allowed to choose v in U such that v - 0 in U, right? And as it seems, this is a result of the definition of V/U itself. Because if I would be allowed to do so, then [0] includes every element of U, since v - 0 in U is satisfied by all Elements v in U, but that contradicts your statement from above.